# Is there unreachable code in this snippet? I don't think so, but Resharper is telling me otherwise

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-3.5, resharper

I have the following method I came across in a code review. Inside the loop Resharper is telling me that `if (narrativefound == false)` is incorrect becuase `narrativeFound` is always true. I don't think this is the case, because in order to set `narrativeFound` to true it has to pass the conditional string compare first, so how can it always be true? Am I missing something? Is this a bug in Resharper or in our code?

```
public Chassis GetChassisForElcomp(SPPA.Domain.ChassisData.Chassis asMaintained, SPPA.Domain.ChassisData.Chassis newChassis)
{
    Chassis c = asMaintained;
    List<Narrative> newNarrativeList = new List<Narrative>();

    foreach (Narrative newNarrative in newChassis.Narratives)
    {
         bool narrativefound = false; 

         foreach (Narrative orig in asMaintained.Narratives)
         {
                if (string.Compare(orig.PCode, newNarrative.PCode) ==0 )
                {
                          narrativefound = true;
                          if (newNarrative.NarrativeValue.Trim().Length != 0)
                          {
                             orig.NarrativeValue = newNarrative.NarrativeValue;
                             newNarrativeList.Add(orig);                            
                          }
                          break;
                }
                if (narrativefound == false)
                {
                     newNarrativeList.Add(newNarrative); 
                }
         }
    }

    c.SalesCodes = newChassis.SalesCodes;
    c.Narratives = newNarrativeList;
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: Looks reachable to me.  Might be a good thing to write a test case for and throw in your test harness to see if you can hit it for code coverage anyway.  You **do** have tests, right?  :)

Comment: Not once have I ever found a resharper "code unreachable" to be incorrect. Although at times it has taken me some serious pondering to find out why. I'm not saying you should always just trust resharper and delete whatever it tells you that you can safely delete, but don't jump to the conclusion that it's incorrect. a debugging step-through of this code would've shown you what was going on.

Comment: Seems like the error here is in interpreting the error code, seems like "Extraneous code" error would have been more helpful than "Unreachable code".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The variable `narrativefound` will never be true when control reaches that statement:

```
narrativefound = true;
// ...
break;  // This causes control to break out of the loop.
```

I think Resharper is trying to tell you that the condition `narrativefound == false` will always be true.

Comment: Exactly - the *condition* will always be true; `narrativeFound` will always be false.

Comment: Good eye. Missed that on the first pass myself.

Comment: I misinterpreted what R# was telling me. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `narrativeFound` variable at all.  In the scope where you set it true, you break from the `foreach` loop.  If you don't set it to true, you don't break, and you add the `newNarrative` to the `newNarrativeList`.

So, this could be rewritten as

```
foreach (Narrative newNarrative in newChassis.Narratives)
{
     foreach (Narrative orig in asMaintained.Narratives)
     {
            if (string.Compare(orig.PCode, newNarrative.PCode) == 0)
            {
                      if (newNarrative.NarrativeValue.Trim().Length != 0)
                      {
                         orig.NarrativeValue = newNarrative.NarrativeValue;
                         newNarrativeList.Add(orig);                            
                      }
                      break;
            }

            newNarrativeList.Add(newNarrative);                 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in your code.

```
foreach (Narrative newNarrative in newChassis.Narratives) 
{ 
     bool narrativefound = false;  

     foreach (Narrative orig in asMaintained.Narratives) 
     { 
            if (string.Compare(orig.PCode, newNarrative.PCode) ==0 ) 
            { 
                      narrativefound = true; 
                      if (newNarrative.NarrativeValue.Trim().Length != 0) 
                      { 
                         orig.NarrativeValue = newNarrative.NarrativeValue; 
                         newNarrativeList.Add(orig);                             
                      } 
// narrativeFound == true, but now we exit the for loop
                      break; 
            } 
// narrativeFound is always false here.  The test is redundant
            if (narrativefound == false) 
            { 
                 newNarrativeList.Add(newNarrative);  
            } 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

R# is correct because if you turn narrativefound to true you are breaking out of the foreach right after you set it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is telling you that becuase IF narriativefound is set to true then the for loop is exited (break;).  So if the if (narriativefound == false) is evaluated it will always have a value of false.